# upload a simple json file to google storage from a simple python script

Tags: python, json, upload, google-cloud-storage

I have a .json local file and I want to upload it to google cloud storage using Python.

First note that my python script is not on app-engine, it's a simple script so I don't want to use the appengine API. Secondly, I read [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gspythonlibrary) and I think it is extremely unclear.

Hence, I am looking for an alternative API, maybe wrote by someone outside from Google, to help me upload my json file using my json credentials.

Comment: This is what you're looking for: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/

Comment: Thank you, but where does this API come from? I am lost with all those APIs.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/#Python_Cloud_Storage_REST_API

Comment: No worries mate. I did. Its a bit tricky to get it working, but you'll get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to interact with google cloud storage services outside of the App Engine environment, you may use `Gcloud` (https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/) to do so.

You need a service account on your application as well as download the JSON credentials file. With those, once you install the proper packages, you'll be able to make queries as well as write data.

Here is an example of authenticating yourself to use the library:

```
from gcloud import datastore

# the location of the JSON file on your local machine
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/location/client_secret.json"


# project ID from the Developers Console
projectID = "THE_ID_OF_YOUR_PROJECT"

os.environ["GCLOUD_TESTS_PROJECT_ID"] = projectID
os.environ["GCLOUD_TESTS_DATASET_ID"] = projectID
client = datastore.Client(dataset_id=projectID)
```

Edit:

This library is for the following as per the docs here(https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python):

This client supports the following Google Cloud Platform services:

```
Google Cloud Datastore
Google Cloud Storage
Google Cloud Pub/Sub
Google BigQuery
Google Cloud Resource Manager
```

Comment: I asked about GCS (google cloud storage), not the Datastore.

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-python and that's what I gave you. Don't be so quick to down vote :(. I just put Datastore there because that's what I used it for. It works on Google Cloud Storage too.